# Specifying quantity in PEG.js

Tags: javascript, regex, peg, pegjs

I'm playing around with [PEG.js](http://pegjs.org/online)

How can I allow to enter exactly 2 letters?

This is my approach:

```
start = word 
word = [A-Za-z]{2}
```

I used the `{2}` from regex, but unfortunately it doesn't work with PEG.js.

Comment: Something like `{ //
  function twoLetterWord(o) { //
    if (o.length == 2) {  //
       return o  //
    } //
    else fail; //
  } //
} //
 // 
start = word //
word "word" //
= word:[A-Za-z]+ { return twoLetterWord(word); }`? I could not find a way to fail the parser manually though. :(

Comment: If I am not mistaken to throw an error you use: error("error message"). You can also pass the location() field into it (it will contain it by default either way).

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a letter class, then use two letters for your word. Although the syntax isn't pretty, I couldn't find another way in the [documentation](http://pegjs.org/documentation#grammar-syntax-and-semantics-parsing-expression-types).

```
start = word
word = letter letter
letter = [A-Za-z]
```

Comment: You can add `i` after the closing square bracket to match case-insensitively. Also, you *could* duplicate the letter class, although it isn't very pretty: `[a-z]i [a-z]i`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see it you can use two options. The first option accepts only a word with two letters.

```
start = word 
word = [A-Za-z][A-Za-z]
```

This second option does some post-processing in javascript.

```
start = word 
word = word:([A-Za-z]+)
{
    if(word.length != 2) error("Word does not have two letters);
    else return word;
}
```